Cannot add spacing in Thymeleaf
HTMl template thymeleaf Code below -(other code is different using div and span tag )
WHOLE Frontend CODE
    <!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Engage Mate - Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- use the font -->
    <style>
        .vi-page-branding {
            background: #FFF;
            padding-top: 22px  !important;
        }

        [class*='vi-']:not(.vi-container),
        [class*='gw-']:not(.gw-container) {
            font-family: "Avenir Next", sans-serif;
        }

        @media (min-width: 1024px) {
            .vi-page-branding__main {
                height: 4.375rem;
                padding: 0 1.875rem;
            }

<!--            .vi-page-branding__logo {-->
<!--                width: 6.25rem;-->
<!--            }-->

        }

        .vi-page-branding__main {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0 1.25rem;
            height: 3.125rem;
            max-width: 1440px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .vi-page-branding__logo img {
            display: block;
        }

        img {
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-style: none;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .vi-page-branding__link {
            text-decoration: none !important;
            display: flex;
        }

<!--        .vi-page-branding__logo {-->
<!--            width: 4.0625rem;-->
<!--        }-->
    </style>
    <style>
        .social-icons li a,
        a.social-icon {
            width: 28px;
            height: 28px;
            display: block;
            background-position: 0 0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .rounded-x {
            border-radius: 50% !important;
        }

        .social_linkedin {
            background: url(https://www.cresensolutions.com/assets//img/icons/social/linkedin.png) no-repeat;
        }


        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            color: #333;
            font-size: 13px;
            line-height: 1.6;

        }

        .footer-v1 .footer {
            padding: 10px 0;
            background: #272727;
        }

        .row {
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-left: -15px;
        }

        .col-md-6 {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .col-md-3 {
            width: 25%;
        }


        .col-md-6,
        .col-md-3 {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 1px;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        .footer-v1 .footer p {
            color: #eee;
        }

        .headline {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px 0 25px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #e4e9f0;
        }

        .footer-v1 .footer h2 {
            color: #eee;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 200;
        }

        .headline h2 {
            font-size: 22px;
            margin: 0 0 -2px 0;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #3498db;
        }

        .list-unstyled {
            padding-left: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }


        .footer-v1 .link-list li {
            border-top: solid 1px #353535;
        }

        .link-list li:first-child {
            border-top: none !important;
        }

        .link-list li {
            border-top: solid 1px #353535;
        }

        p,
        li,
        li a,
        label {
            color: #555;
        }

        .footer-v1 address,
        .footer-v1 .link-list a,
        .footer-v1 .link-list i {
            color: #eee;
        }

        .footer a,
        .copyright a,
        .footer a:hover,
        .copyright a:hover {
            color: #3498db;
        }

        .link-list a {
            color: #eee;
            font-size: 11px;
            padding: 6px 0px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        a,
        a:focus,
        a:hover,
        a:active {
            outline: 0 !important;
        }

        a {
            color: #337ab7;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: transparent;
        }


        .footer-v1 .footer .map-img {
            background: url(https://www.cresensolutions.com/assets/img/map-img.png) 5px 60px no-repeat;
        }

        .footer-v1 address {
            line-height: 23px;
        }

        .footer-v1 address,
        .footer-v1 .link-list a,
        .footer-v1 .link-list i {
            color: #eee;
        }

        address {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-style: normal;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
        }

        .footer-v1 .copyright {
            background: #222;
            border-top: none;
            padding: 10px 0 5px;
        }

        .wrapper {
            background: #fff;
        }

        .row:after,
        .row:before {
            display: table;
            content: " ";
        }



        .footer-v1 .copyright p {
            color: #eee;
            margin-top: 14px;
        }

        .container {
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

            .footer-v1 .copyright,
            .footer-v1 .footer-socials {
                text-align: left;
            }

            .md-margin-bottom-40 {
                margin-bottom: 40px;
            }
        }

        .social-icons li:hover a {
            background-position: 0 -38px;
        }

        .footer a,
        .copyright a,
        .footer a:hover,
        .copyright a:hover {
            color: #3498db;
        }

        .footer-v1 .copyright a {
            margin: 0 2px;
        }

        .font-weight-bold{
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div class="row" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px; background-color: #ffffff">
    <p><span th:text="${mailDear}"></span> <span th:text="${username}"></span>,</p>
    <p><span th:text="${mailSubmitterActivityReviewCompletedMessage}"></span>.</p>
    <div th:switch="${tenantId}">
        <div th:case="'teva'">
            <p><a th:href="@{${link}}"><span th:text="${mailLink}"></span></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><span th:text="${mailActivityId}"></span>: <span th:text="${activityId}"></span></p>
    <p><span th:text="${mailActivityType}"></span>: <span th:text="${activityName}"></span></p>
    <p><span th:text="${mailActivityTitle}"></span>: <span th:text="${activityTitle}"></span></p>
    <div th:switch="${tenantId}">
        <div th:case="'teva'">
            <p><span th:text="${mailProduct}"></span>: <span th:text="${productOrTherapeuticArea}"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><span th:text="${mailSubmitterName}"></span>: <span th:text="${submitterName}"></span></p>
    <p><span th:text="${mailActivityStartDate}"></span>: <span th:text="${activityStartDate}"></span></p>
    <div th:switch="${tenantId}">
        <div th:case= "'insmed'">
            <p><span th:text="${mailOwnerName}"></span>: <span th:text="${ownerName}"></span></p>
            <p><span th:text="${mailProduct}"></span>: <span th:text="${product}"></span></p>
            <p><span th:text="${mailSubmittedDate}"></span>: <span th:text="${submittedDate}"></span></p>
            <p><span th:text="${mailReviewersName}"></span>: <span th:text="${reviewerName}"></span></p>   --------------------------THIS LINE I NEED TO change
        </div>
        <div th:case="'teva'">
            <p><span th:text="${mailProjectOriginator}"></span>: <span th:text="${projectOriginator}"></span></p>
            <p><span th:text="${mailSubRoleName}"></span>: <span th:text="${subRoleName}"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="font-weight-bold"><span th:text="${reviewerComments}"></span></p>
    <br></br>
    <div th:switch="${tenantId}">
        <div th:case= "'insmed'">
            <p><span th:text="${mailPleaseClickOnThe}"></span> <a th:href="@{${link}}"><span th:text="${mailLink}"></span></a> <span th:text="${mailToReviewTheActivity}"></span>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p><span th:text="${mailNote}"></span></p>
    <br></br>
    <p><span th:text="${mailRegards}"></span>,</p>
    <p><span th:text="${teamName}"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="vi-page-branding">
    <div class="vi-page-branding__main">
        <a class="vi-page-branding__link" href="#" rel="home">
            <div class="vi-page-branding__logo">
                <div th:switch="${tenantId}">
                    <div th:case= "'insmed'">
                        <img src="cid:insmedLogo" alt="Insmed Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd."/>
                    </div>
                    <div th:case="'teva'">
                        <img src="cid:tevaLogo" alt="Teva Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd."/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
----------------------------------------------------------------
<p class="font-weight-bold"><span th:text="${reviewerComments}"></span></p> - this is working fine check in above whole code
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 <p class="font-weight-bold">Reviewer Comments:</p>      -  i have tried this , replacement not working?
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="comment : ${#strings.split(reviewerComments, ' \\| ')}" th:with="fields=${#strings.split(comment, ' - ')}">
            <td th:text="${fields[0]}"></td>
            <td th:text="${fields[1]}"></td>
            <td th:text="${fields[2]}"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

Backend - this is sending the value to reviewerComments variable in frontend , want minimal change in backend
   private String getActivityApprovedComments(String activityId, String action) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        List<ActivityApprovalAudit> activityApprovalAuditList = activityApprovalAuditService.fetchActivityApprovalAuditByActivityIdAndAction(activityId, action);
        if (activityApprovalAuditList != null && !activityApprovalAuditList.isEmpty()) {
            for(ActivityApprovalAudit activityApprovalAudit: activityApprovalAuditList) {
                long userId = activityApprovalAudit.getUserId();
                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> user = util.getUserByUserId(userId);
                String reviewerName = Util.convertToString(user.get(USER_FULL_NAME));
                sb.append(reviewerName)
                        .append(" - ")
                        .append(CommonConstants.APPROVED)
                        .append(" on ").append(activityApprovalAudit.getCreatedDate())
                        .append(" - ")
                        .append(activityApprovalAudit.getComment())
                        .append("|"); // also try to change here with \n, br and other tag not wokring.
            }
            return sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 3);
        }
        else return sb.toString();
    }

right now outout is coming like this
user1 - Approved on Date - comment1 | user2 - Approved on Date - comment2
spacing is not woking either from backend or from frontends already use .append("\n) in backned and br tag in frontend
I need this OUTPUT:
if 3 Reviewer
Reviewer 3 Name: Approved on Date – Comments
Reviewer 2 Name: Approved on Date – Comments
Reviewer 1 Name: Approved on Date – Comments
if 2 Reviewer
Reviewer 2 Name: Approved on Date – Comments
Reviewer 1 Name: Approved on Date – Comments
 - so right i am getting this outlook reply.. i just want to change in reviewer comment in below format .!
Problem is I have tried multiple spacing and <br> tag and &nbsp; but not working in email notification. Even in backend I have tried \n instead of pipes but nothing working. Am I missing something? Please write a code in HTML Thymeleaf using table or something, so that it will give same output as mentioned specifically spacing issue and make sure it should process. I have tried bunch of solutions. The problem is HTML Thymeleaf did not process after changing in HTML. Might that be a tag issue?
